# Добавление процентов drop-down меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
                <select name="percentage" id="percentage" class="js-select">
                    <option value="1.15">Идеальное</option>
                    <option value="1">Хорошее</option>
                    <option value="2">Плохое</option>
                    <option value="3">Сломанное</option>
                </select>
                <span id="purchase_price">3000</span> до <span id="purchasse_price">5000</span>
<script>
$("#percentage").change(function () {
    var perc = parseFloat($("#purchase_price").val());
    var purch = parseFloat($("#percentage").val());

    $("#purchase_price").val((purch * perc).toFixed(2));
});
</script>
```

Существует задумка, при выборе select`a должны добавляться проценты к числу в #purchase_price, а при выборе другого определенного option, минусоваться проценты от числа в #purchasse_price, но то что написал - не работает почему то и в #purchase_price - число не меняется. Подскажите, где что-то упустил? :(

Comment: для #purchase_price нет метода val(). Есть метод text()

Comment: `<script>
$("#percentage").change(function () {
    var perc = parseFloat($("#purchase_price").text());
    var purch = parseFloat($("#percentage").val());

    $("#purchase_price").text((purch * perc).toFixed(2));
});
</script>`

Даже так не сработало, @soledar10

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzcr6g71/

Comment: @soledar10 Премного благодарен, заработал метод, а при выборе допустим 3 option`a - возможно ли сделать чтобы purchasse_price минусовал процент? В том же скрипте или нужно создавать ещё один select?